# How to increase resolution of ggplots when exporting using officer R

Tags: r, ggplot2, officer

I want to export charts to a PPT and am using the officer package to achieve the same. However, the default resolution of the charts is low and I would like to change that. I am currently using the following call

```
    ph_with_gg(p1,type = "chart",res = 1200)
```

where p1 is a ggplot object. On running this, I get the following error:

```
    Error in png(filename = file, width = width, height = height, units = 
"in",  : 
  formal argument "res" matched by multiple actual arguments
```

Would really appreciate the help around this

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Rather than using `png`, for high-resolution plots in PPT you should be using **vector graphics**.

See under [extensions](https://github.com/davidgohel/officer):

> **Vector graphics with package `rvg`**
>
> The package [rvg](https://github.com/davidgohel/rvg) brings an API to
>   produce nice vector graphics that can be embedded in PowerPoint
>   documents or Excel workbooks with `officer`.

This package provides functions `dml()` and `ph_with()` corresponding method to export ggplots to .pptx as vector graphics.

Example:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(officer)
library(rvg)
library(magrittr)
data(iris)

read_pptx() %>%
  add_slide(layout='Title and Content',master='Office Theme') %>%
  ph_with('Iris Sepal Dimensions', location = ph_location_type(type="title")) %>%
  ph_with(dml( ggobj=
                 ggplot(iris, aes(x=Sepal.Length,y=Sepal.Width,col=Species)) +
                 geom_point()), location = ph_location_type(type="body")) %>%
  print('iris_presentation.pptx')
```

As an additional benefit, you will be able to edit the charts in PowerPoint.  For example, if you decided to capitalize the names of the 3 species, you could just edit the chart instead of editing the data and regenerating the slides.  (You can also make the plots non-editable, but editable is the default.)

Comment: Thanks for pointing to this package. It has a function called ph_with_vg which solves the problem. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

Is it important that the plot is saved to a presentation in the code?

Otherwise using:

```
ggsave(filename = file, p1, width = width, height = height, dpi = dpi)
```

will give you a png of any resolution you need..

(provided that filename ends with .png and you set width, height and dpi to appropriate values)

Comment: Hi. How do you know what value is appropriate to set the dpi?